# Can I use type declaration inside Haskell code

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell, and I have a little question about function type declaration. Suppose there are bunch of integers, we need to sum it and print it out. I am aware this works:

`main = do
  a <- fmap (map read . words) getContents :: IO [Int]
  print $ sum a`

but`a <- fmap (map (read :: Int) . words) getContents`failed. Why it failed? We know `getContents` is `IO String`, then `words` is dealing with `String` and return `[String]` to `map (read :: Int)`, I thought it may goes fine, because we declared it to read an `Int`, but it failed.

Is it impossible to use type declaration inside a line of code, or I use it the wrong way. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `read` doesn't have the type `Int`, it has the type `String -> Int` (for your purposes).  The `map` function only accepts a function as its first argument, and you're trying to say that `read` has type `Int`, which would mean it's not a function.  There's also no way you can coerce the type `Read a => String -> a` to `Int`, so it would error on both of these problems.

Comment: thanks very much! I change it to `fmap (map (read :: String -> Int) . words) getContents`, and it runs ok.